# Merge two tables with same columns and get the column value in specific table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables that have the same column of position and salary.

**Table_a**

| ID | Name | Position | Salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Peter | Sale | 10,000 |
| 2 | Tom | IT | 15,000 |
| 3 | Jane | Sale | 12,000 |
| 4 | Mary | PR | 8,000 |
| 5 | John | IT | 14,000 |

**Table_b**

| ID | Position | Salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Driver | 9,000 |
| 2 | Manager | 20,000 |
| 4 | Sale | 13,000 |

I would like to merge two tables that the output is based on the Position value and Salary value of Table_b.

**Output**

| ID | Name | Position | Salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Peter | Driver | 9,000 |
| 2 | Tom | Manager | 20,000 |
| 3 | Jane | Sale | 12,000 |
| 4 | Mary | Sale | 13,000 |
| 5 | John | IT | 14,000 |

Please give me an advice how can I query and get the above output.

Comment: what did you try yourself to get the wanted output?  Why did you not re-read your question after posting (and notice that bad format?)

Comment: Also question is unclear, because `Peter` has a salary of 10.000 (in Table_a), and in your final result a salary of 9.000 .  But for `John` the salary is the same.  You should provide a description which explains this behavior. (to avoid _wrong_ answers)

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT id, 
       t1.name, 
       COALESCE(t2.position, t1.position), 
       COALESCE(t2.salary, t1.salary)
FROM table_a t1
LEFT JOIN table_b t2 USING (id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Some rows in `table_a` don't have a matching row in `table_b`. Any rows in `table_b` that don't have a matching row in `table_a` will be ignored. We assume that `ID` is unique in each table (meaning for example there won't be two rows in `table_b` with the same ID value). We will match the rows on `ID` value.

---

We can make `table_a` the driving table in an outer join to `table_b`. Let's first get that working, returning all the columns from both tables, and verify the return is what we expect.

```
SELECT a.ID
     , a.Name
     , a.Position
     , a.Salary
     , b.ID            AS b_ID
     , b.Position      AS b_position
     , b.Salary        AS b_salary
  FROM table_a a
  LEFT
  JOIN table_b b
    ON b.ID = a.ID
 ORDER
    BY a.ID
```

We see that in the result from the first query, on rows where we didn't get a matching row from table_b,  column `b_ID` (and all the columns from table_b) are NULL.

We can add some expressions in the SELECT list to get the `Salary` from `table_b` where we found a matching row, or otherwise return `Salary` from `table_a` where we didn't.

There's lots of possible expressions to do that, but they all key on the idea that when we don't have a matching row from the outer joined table, the values in those columns will be NULL.

So the trick is test whether we found a matching row from `table_b` (or if we did get a matching row in `table_b`, the row had a NULL value for `Salary`)

Adding some example expressions to check if `b.ID` or `b.Salary` is NULL.

```
SELECT a.Name
     , a.Position
     , a.Salary
     , b.ID            AS b_ID
     , b.Position      AS b_position
     , b.Salary        AS b_salary

     , CASE WHEN b.ID IS NULL THEN a.Salary ELSE b.Salary END AS _Salary_x1
     , IFNULL(b.Salary,a.Salary)              AS _Salary_x2 
     , IF(b.Salary IS NULL,a.Salary,b.Salary) AS _Salary_x3 

  FROM table_a a
  LEFT
  JOIN table_b b
    ON b.ID = a.ID
 ORDER
    BY a.ID
```

Comment: Yes... Some rows in table_a don't have a matching row in table_b. And ID is Staff ID or Primary key. When compare table_a's ID and table_b's ID... If table_b has the ID that matched with table_a's ID, that row output will be shown the salary and position of table_b. If not output still be shown salary and position of table_a.